# do you need the ref or out parameter?

Tags: c#, oop

I am passing a instance of a class to a method, and that method will modify the instance.

Do I need to use the out or ref keyword since this is a class I am passing?

This is what I want to do:

```
public void Blah()
{
   Blah b = Dao.GetBlah(23);

   SomeService.ModifyXml(b);    // do I need to use out or ref here?

   Dao.SaveXml(b.xml);

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The right way to think about this is: **use ref/out when you want to create an alias to a variable**. That is, when you say:

```
void M(ref int x) { x = 10; }
...
int q = 123;
M(ref q);
```

what you are saying is *"x is another name for the variable q"*.  Any changes to the **contents** of x change q, and any changes to the contents of q change x, because x and q are just two names for the *exact same storage location*.

Notice that this is completely different from two variables referring to the same object:

```
object y = "hello";
object z = y;
```

Here we have *two variables*, each variable has *one name*, each variable refers to *one object*, and the two variables both refer to the *same object*. With the previous example, we have only *one variable* with *two names*.

Is that clear?

Comment: In all the times I taught C#, I wish I'd thought of this way to explain the `ref` concept. +1, clear, concise and meaningful.

Comment: Yes, it is clear, but do you need to use ref for the object? I understand that you need to do this to change a value type, but want about a reference type?

Comment: @AMissico: apparently it is not clear because your question indicates that you don't understand it. Whether the variable is of reference type or value type or pointer type is completely irrelevant. Use an out/ref parameter *when you wish to make an alias for an existing variable*. Use a regular parameter when you wish to create a new variable. That's all there is to it; what the variable's type is doesn't come into it.

Comment: Lippet: I only understand after reading JMD, David M, and Sam's answers. I believe your answer only confuses, and does not directly address the question. Especially, when you pass an int in your sample. Of course, when passing a value type you need to "pass the reference", an alias, if you wish. Do I need to use ref for making changes to an object? The answer is no, unless I want to change what object the "alias/reference/pointer" points,.

Answer (score 5):

If the reference `b` is not being modified, and only `b`'s properties are being modified then you need neither `ref` nor `out`.  Both of those would be approriate only if the reference itself was being modified.

I've expanded your sample code a bit to include usage for `ref`, `out`, and neither:

http://pastebin.ca/1749793

[Snip]

```
public void Run()
{
    Blah b = Dao.GetBlah(23);

    SomeService.ModifyXml(b);    // do I need to use out or ref here?
    Dao.SaveXml(b.Xml);

    SomeService.SubstituteNew(out b);
    Dao.SaveXml(b.Xml);

    SomeService.ReadThenReplace(ref b);
    Dao.SaveXml(b.Xml);
}
```

The rest of the code is in that PasteBin.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not want ref or out here.  You want to use ref when the method will change the object that the parameter points to.  You want to use out when the method will always specify a new object for the parameter to point to.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't. The default behaviour when passing an instance of a reference type as a parameter is to pass its reference by value. This means you can alter the current instance, but not swap it out for another different instance. If this is what you mean by "modify the instance", then you you don't need `ref` or `out`.

Comment: the method ModifyXml will set the xml propert of the class Blah, and then I save it to the db.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check is with intellisense: hover your mouse over `ModifyXml` and if the parameter in the method signature contains `out`, such as `ModifyXml( out Blah blah )`, then you need the `out` keyword. Same goes for `ref`.